# CVPixelBuffer Writing using UIImage.draw() is TOO SLOW

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, coreml

I'm an undergraduate student and I'm now using CoreML frame to do some video HumanSeg app on iPhone, but as the title shows, I've got a huuuuuge problem.

I have a UIImage and I have to resize and pad it, and draw it into a CVPixelBuffer to feed the MobileNet model, but such process is just TOO SLOW, costing about 30ms, which is unacceptable.

To be specific, In my code, method UIImage.draw(in: CGRect(x: Int, y: Int, width: Int, height: Int)) is TOO SLOW, and took me 20+ ms, which is the major issue.

My codes are below:

```
func dealRawImage(image : UIImage, dstshape : [Int], pad : UIImage) -> CVPixelBuffer?
{
    // decide whether to shrink in height or width
    let height = image.size.height
    let width = image.size.width
    let ratio = width / height
    let dst_width = Int(min(CGFloat(dstshape[1]) * ratio, CGFloat(dstshape[0])))
    let dst_height = Int(min(CGFloat(dstshape[0]) / ratio, CGFloat(dstshape[1])))
    let origin = [Int((dstshape[0] - dst_height) / 2), Int((dstshape[1] - dst_width) / 2)]

    // init a pixelBuffer to store the resized & padded image
    var pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer?
    let attrs = [kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey: kCFBooleanTrue,
                 kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey: kCFBooleanTrue]
    CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                        dstshape[1],
                        dstshape[0],
                        kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB,
                        attrs as CFDictionary,
                        &pixelBuffer)

    // get the pointer of this pixelBuffer
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer!, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))
    let pixelData = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer!)

    // init a context that contains this pixelBuffer to draw in
    let context = CGContext(data: pixelData,
                            width: dstshape[1],
                            height: dstshape[0],
                            bitsPerComponent: 8,
                            bytesPerRow: CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(pixelBuffer!),
                            space: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(),
                            bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.noneSkipFirst.rawValue)!

    // push context
    UIGraphicsPushContext(context)
    context.translateBy(x: 0, y: CGFloat(dstshape[0]))
    context.scaleBy(x: 1, y: -1)

    pad.draw(in:CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: dstshape[1], height: dstshape[0]))
    // THIS SINGLE FUNCTION COSTS ME 20+ ms AND IS THE MAJOR ISSUE !
    image.draw(in: CGRect(x: origin[1], y: origin[0], width: dst_width, height: dst_height))

    UIGraphicsPopContext()

    // unlock
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer!, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))

    return pixelBuffer
}
```

And I just call this function like this:

```
let input = dealRawImage(image: raw_input_image, dstshape: [224, 224], pad: black_image)
```

Where raw_input_image is the UIImage I read from memory, dstshape is the shape I want to resize this image to, and black_image is a totally black UIImage used for padding.

I've searched on this website but no familiar issue was found.

Is there any way I can make this process faster and save this project? I just don't want to abandon my 2-week work.

Comment: I'm not sure why the line with `image.draw()` is so much slower than `pad.draw()` [possibly because of the resizing] but two questions come to mind here: 1) why do you need to do padding on your input image? 2) if you need speed, why is your input data in a UIImage?

Comment: Oh, one thing I would try is making `image.draw()` use 0, 0 and the full width and height, and see if that is any faster.

Comment: Thanks. And let me answer your questions first. 1) I got the trained MoblieNet model from my lab, and my seniors made the black padding to the image when training this model, so I also need to do this to make this net run correctly. 2) I'm not sure what I can use if I need to pick images from iPhone camera or album. I also tried to use opencv-swift, but there were something wrong and I came back to UIImage in the end. 3) Do you mean that using other image formats may generate a CVPixelBuffer faster?

Comment: So is it faster if you use (0, 0) instead of (1, 1) and the full width and height to draw the image? If yes, then I'd just do that and forget about the black border. (Or if you really really really must have a black border, just draw it on top of the image.)

Comment: If you’re working with video, you should be able to use GPU-accelerated pixel buffers for frames from the start. Whatever intermediary step gets you *into* doing CPU-based drawing with UIImage is the bottleneck, and trying to go from UIImage back to GPU-backed pixel buffers is just compounding your original problem. So how is it you’re using UIImage in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a while since I've dealt with `CVPixelBuffer`s, and I haven't used `CoreML` at all yet.

When I **did** work with `CVPixelBuffer`s, I found that I got the best performance by creating a single pixel buffer at the target size and keeping it around. I was taking pixels from the camera, passing them to OpenGL as a texture, manipulating them, and mapping the output into the same CVPixelBuffer. I was able to use the same memory structure for all of that. I suggest taking that approach.

Comment: Yeah, but even though I create a CVPixelBuffer and use it throughout the project, writing data into it is still too slow. In fact, to create one I only need 9 ms, but to write UIImage data (using draw() method) into it I need 20+ ms and that's the major issue, I think. Is there any solution?

Comment: Use OpenGL or metal and draw textures with the pixel buffer set as the output of the OpenGL "context." It's been so long since I've worked on this stuff that I don't even remember the terms for it.

Comment: In my app I'm able to take frames from the camera, map them to textures, do a "mesh warp" on the texture, map the output back to a pixel buffer and render to the screen at a full 60 fps.